# SwiftUI List editing with some rows .moveDisabled(true): missing destinations

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a very simple editable `SwiftUI` `List` with a few rows set to `.moveDisabled(true)`

For easier testing, the background of the fixed rows is red.

This is the complete runnable code of the demo:

```
import SwiftUI

class Model: ObservableObject {
    struct Item: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var name: String
        var isFixed: Bool
    }
    
    @Published var items: [Item] = [
        Item(name: "Fixed 1", isFixed: true),
        Item(name: "Movable 1", isFixed: false),
        Item(name: "Movable 2", isFixed: false),
        Item(name: "Fixed 2", isFixed: true),
        Item(name: "Movable 3", isFixed: false),
        Item(name: "Movable 4", isFixed: false)
    ]
    
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        items.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(model.items) { item in
                    if item.isFixed {
                        Text(item.name)
                            .listRowBackground(Color.red)
                            .moveDisabled(true)
                    } else {
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                }
                .onMove(perform: model.move)
            }
            .listStyle(.grouped)
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyPreviewProvider_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Problem: when dragging a moveable row across a non moveable row, the next spot after the non movable row is not available as destination.
After dropping a moveable row, the destination is available again, if not crossing a non moveable row.

This happens in both cases, when crossing from top to bottom and when crossing from bottom to top.

Demo:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Apple bug?
Is there a way/workaround that allows to use any destination index for dragging?

Tested with iOS 16.4 and iOS 17.0beta2

P.S.
Even worse: if two adjacent rows are not moveable, it is not possible to move a moveable row in between.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this appears to be a bug.

I have developed a hacky workaround that appears to work in my testing.

Assuming that the first element is a heading for a section, only set `.moveDisabled(true)` for that element. For the other fixed elements, set the frame `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` to `.infinity` with a background color and empty `.onLongPressGesture`:

```
ForEach(model.items) { item in
  if item.isFixed {
    Text("\(group.order) \(group.title ?? "Unnamed group")")
      .moveDisabled(item == model.items.first!)
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
      .background(.white)
      .onLongPressGesture { }
  } else {
    Text("Moveable item")
  }
}
```

The `.onLongPressGesture` will prevent moving from triggering. Any of the moveable items can be moved anywhere, except for before the first item which is fixed in place.

You can't use `.background(.clear)` as the `.onLongPressGesture` will only trigger when directly over the text (e.g. you can still start moving from empty space on view) so you will need to match the background color of the view to the background of list.